# How is the community doing? [2018]

Tags: discussion, community-check-in

<sub>*(Largely cribbed from the 2017 check-in)*</sub>

We, the elected moderators, wanted to take a minute to check in and see how the community feels like things are going on the site. About [a year ago we did this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6895/23970) and felt that it was pretty helpful in putting specificity on some issues, productively talking through some things, and recognizing where communication breakdowns were happening. It also [prompted an election](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6897/23970)!

Out of that we were reminded of some things going well. We encouraged more and have seen more involvement/leadership from "regular" moderators--users who have reached [moderation privileges](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). We've quickly dealt with some abusive users--hopefully quickly enough that few of you even noticed! (Though some did, and your flags and pings are *really* helpful when you see something going wrong.)

So again we'd like to share our thoughts and also get yours on what is going well and what could improve.

---

#### How this specific Q&A is run so that we get good value out of it.

We'll post some of the things we've done/observations we have/things we think still need improvement.  Please do the same.

1. Post one kind of thing per answer, so that when people
   upvote/downvote based on whether they agree or not it's more clearly
   actionable - if you write an essay about 4 different things, it's
   not going to be clear what part(s) people agree or disagree with.
2. Upvote or downvote based on your agreement.

   Let's not have long comment threads -
3. If you disagree with an answer, post your own answer.

   This isn't just being pedantic.  If we have a 30-comment thread on an answer, what does that tell us we need to do?  Mostly it tells us whether one person is really irritated instead of whether a large part of the community disagrees, which is what we kinda want to get to.
4. As usual, Be Nice applies to meta as well as the main site.

   You may strongly disagree with other users or with the mods or whoever, but we trust you can find ways to express what you like or don't like without being hostile or insulting to others. Focus on actions rather than characterizing people.

So here we go - our thoughts on things that are going well or need improvement. Feel free and add on!

Comment: This is the first time I've been around for one of these "How is the community doing?" posts... how do they work? Are the answers supposed to be our own opinions/thoughts? Are they supposed to discuss specific matters?

Comment: @V2Blast This is the second ever time it's happened, and last time it was immediately following Bad Stuff.  I don't think we have anything like an established etiquette, yet, but last time I posted my thoughts on stuff I thought were Things (stuff we were doing well, or badly, or just doing and and worth mentioning) with one item per post, and that seemed to go over well.  I'd strongly advise against putting more than one Thing in an answer, because voting.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for responding.

Comment: This is not an answer on purpose because I have not actually been here enough over the last year and so I have only an abstract feeling: *From the outside* it looks like it took a turn for the better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the community doing? \[2019\]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9048/how-is-the-community-doing-2019)

Comment: @nitsua60 are you going through the motions or does this edit signal that you might want to prepare a new community check-in?

Comment: I was just fixing a typo. Unrelatedly (forrealz), a new check-in has just been created =)

Comment: @nitsua60: But... you changed it from one misspelling to a different misspelling. :P

Comment: @V2Blast <headdesk> It's a good thing I don't work here anymore =\

Answer (score 37):

#### Homebrew-related questions need to be received better

It's taken me a while to find a way to say this, [but this meta question puts a finger on it.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7906/22566)  There is (or seems to be) a *perceived* bias against homebrew that is likely dampening some questions where the community's *experience* and *expertise* in this game form could be of great value.

At the risk of being a Jonny-one-Note, I will again offer a cogent observation on [a core value of RPG.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=42972950#42972950) from @BESW

> We aren't here on the Stack to read the rulebooks to people. We're
>   here to help people learn how to synthesize the mechanics, the
>   non-mechanical text, the social context, our personal experience, the
>   learning of the broader community, to apply all that to a particular
>   real-life problem someone's having and find a solution for it.

Part of the fun of many role playing games is homebrew, or minor adaptations to a rule set *to get the game to fit better at a given table*.  What appears to be happening in some cases (though it's hard for me to put a magnitude on it) is a *received negative connotation* of homebrew.

I tripped over [this comment](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7906/keep-my-homebrew-stuff-secret-in-order-to-avoid-biased-answers#comment25093_7916) and began to wonder how prevalent this perception is.

> This underscores my complaint that moderation by people who are
>   concrete reasoners vs those who are abstract reasoners creates lot of
>   tension on SE, in general. It's probably the #1 reason I see questions
>   on hold, because the questioner used abstract thought process in
>   posting, but the people who put the question on hold are concrete in
>   their reasoning, and can't get beyond the depth of something that was
>   worded just out of their reach. It's painful to watch. – [user9570789
>   20 hours ago](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7906/keep-my-homebrew-stuff-secret-in-order-to-avoid-biased-answers#comment25093_7916)

As @doppelgreener pointed out in a comment under the meta in question, some of this has to do with being open to multiple playstyles, but there may be more to this.  If I can put a name to it (I can't at the moment) I'll either add it to this answer or open another meta.  Full disclosure: I am pretty sure I have been guilty of what that comment complains about at least once, if not multiple times.

#### Actionable Suggestions

(1) Flag and report hostile comments (we should already do that), and be alert for dismissive comments directed at home brew content in questions.

- It seems that VTCs as 'primarily opinion-based' are a common response to such material, as if anything that isn't first-party rules would somehow be off-topic.  (thank you @the dark wanderer).  That does not relieve the requirement to *back it up* -- GS/BS guidance must be respected.

(2) Work with querents to assist with the elements of a homebrew related question that can get an SE style answer, and identify those elements which remain within the domain of a table.  *Tone matters.*

- There was a time when questions involving homebrew got comments along the lines of "How open are you to changing your homebrew?"  These were more common a few years ago than they are now, and are an example of *how comments can help form and frame a question*. (@daze413 thank you)  Part of sharing our expertise is in helping someone to form a better question.  As I learned the first few times I asked questions on RPG.SE, asking a good question (that shows some research) is a bit of an art form.

(3) Use experience with similar homebrew/modification as applicable.

- make sure to link this experience to the problem to be solved in the question, and show how the two situations are similar enough that your experience adds value.

(4) We (the RPG.SE braintrust) need to create a canonical (faq-worthy?) meta post on how to ask good homebrew questions.  Some research project taxonomizing the current homebrew questions would be the next logical step.  (a call of #NotIt has been heard from @nitsua60)

Comment: It seems like a lot of people have the perspective that there can't be objectively correct or helpful answers about homebrew. There can be as long as the parameters are well-defined. I think the SE process works well to revise homebrew questions until they are well-defined enough to be answerable, but it does seem like a lot of people stop at "you shouldn't do this homebrew" or "you've homebrewed, that's your problem." The occasional frame challenge of that sort might be warranted, but I agree with the experience in hohenheim's meta that users are very antagonistic to homebrew questions.

Comment: I will confess to being often tired by and rarely engaging with homebrew questions; I hope that in the process I haven't come across as antagonistic when I do engage. It simply that so many come across where it feels like the querent hasn't done *any* legwork themselves.... It's so that when I see a homebrew question my instinctual reaction is "ugh" and I tab away, maybe coming back to the thing when a flag's been raised.

Comment: I don't want to sound dubious or turn this into finger pointing, but can anybody point me to some examples of where this has happened that I can see and better understand what to look for? I see this issue talked about among at least a few people but I'm not sure I've ever seen a specific example provided. My thoughts on the matter are basically what [nistua60 said](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/how-is-the-community-doing-2018#comment25137_7932), so I may have just missed these things.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose [Here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121109/sentinel-raven-uses-too-much-awesome-magic) is one, and remember that comments get cleaned up so that you may not see the whole story.  When someone offers feedback like this, I think we need to pay attention. Did you take a look at the meta I linked to?  I've been reading a lot of stuff over the past few years, on this site, and I have picked up now and again a (*dismissive* may be the right term) tone that crops up now and again.

Comment: I did read the meta (both when it was posted and again now) and I think I'm seeing it a bit clearer. Have you seen any bleed into answers at all?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I'd need to look at a lot of answers and their edit trails, but what gets me is as much tone as content.  I'll need to think about this and figure out some search terms to try and find examples.  It's one of those "nagging things at the back of my mind" that the meta question got to surface.

Comment: The most flagrant way this happens is via VTCs, esp as 'primarily opinion-based', as-if anything that isn't first-party rules would somehow be off-topic.  I don't want to discourage question closure, because honestly most of the time we need to be a lot better about doing that faster, but nonetheless these aren't 'primarily opinion based' and closing them as such is bad/wrong.

Comment: This is an interesting topic that I feel deserves its own meta question rather than just an answer in this thread. It might even benefit from having multiple meta questions, e.g. One to more closely examine what the problem is and a separate one to discuss solutions.

Comment: @daze413  Good point, I'll add that to the actionable bit

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Wow.  I'm surprised to see someone pick up my comment.  TBH, I'm guilty of the same kind of attitude that I'm complaining about in that comment.  It took me a long time to understand things about myself and other people.  The comment space isn't enough to address this, so I'll throw it into an answer.

Comment: @user9570789 You put your finger on something I wasn't able to name very well.  Thanks, and please add more insights to this process.

Comment: I admit that I'm also not a fan of most homebrew questions — I'd have to think for a while to unpack why, but I can attest that I *feel* what Korvin's describing, so I feel like it's a real thing that's probably not just me. As a mod I do have to self-moderate much harder for things that I simply *dislike*, so I think — I hope — that I haven't actually acted detrimentally regarding homebrew. I would like to see how we handle homebrew questions somehow improve, though I can't say how that might work. There are some great, well-specced homebrew questions, and some that just, ugh, I tab away.

Comment: As long as it's not Rules-As-Written, homebrew away. *As long as you've done it yourself and can speak to it's efficacy.*

Comment: @SevenSidedDie For me, it seems like homebrew is very rarely going to have any objectivity in it's answers, and the good subjectivity we look for seems to get swamped out by people pulling ideas out of their ass. On top of that, "balance" is a very deep dive for many game systems, especially the most popular ones, so it is very hard to write an answer which fits in the stack format.

Comment: @fectin It depends on (1) what's being asked and (2) who is answering.  I agree that the "try this" with no "back it up" isn't what this stack needs more of, nor is that what is being recommended.  As SSD points out, there are some good questions in the homebrew category that attract some good answers. Capturing what makes that successful might take some more discernment.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast true, but "there are some good questions and some good answers" applies equally well to game recommendations.

Comment: @fectin Yeah, and it's a shame that game rec was let go ...

Comment: I am not sure if this applies, but I've been reading old close reasons and found "too localized", maybe that's a thing about homebrew questions...?

Comment: @daze413 It makes no sense to me, maybe an old guard member can elaborate?

Comment: After reading today's homebrew question I feel like we should really be pushing querents to "show your work." Look at how many homebrew questions are posed where it's not even clear if OP *knows* their items/creatures/class features aren't first-party, or where readers lack lots of useful context that later comes out in comment-chains.

Comment: Suggest a 4th action item: a canonical (faq-worthy?) meta post on how to ask good homebrew questions, probably needing to be based on someone's research project taxonomizing the current ones. (#NotIt)

Comment: @nitsua60 done.

Comment: "Too localized" was removed as a close reason network-wide because it was misused, it was meant to be for situations like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized but wasn't used right so got pulled.  A question that just helps you is OK.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth some kind of reminder to users complaining about certain types of questions that they can completely hide (not just grey out) questions of certain tags from the question page by adding a tag to their "ignored tags" section of their profile? It's a feature that surprisingly many people aren't aware of, and for those who get frustrated every time they see a homebrew question or a question about magic item balance (or whatever), it might be a useful panacea.

Comment: @TylerH Suggest starting a meta advertising that feature as a way for improve the user experience might be a good first step.  thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: While I agree with the principles and problems in play, there's a common situation that doesn't seem to be addressed: Homebrew questions are hard to ask in ways that allow for answers that follow good-subjective/bad-subjective guidelines, and so poor quality homebrew questions *are* often primarily opinion-based. These should be closed while the asker is helped to refine the question. That's not a concrete/abstract reasoning problem, it's being able to tell the difference between the written question and the implied question, and protecting it from bad answers while the gap is being bridged.

Comment: @BESW We have down votes to deal with bad answers.

Comment: I'm not talking about bad answers.

Comment: @BESW Then perhaps your point on "protecting from bad answers" was not needed?  Bad answers happen; we downvote, flag, and delete them.  It's a community mod function.  The protect function helps(somewhat) with that without closing, and yes some such questions do indeed benefit from closure due to the larger amount of workshopping needed to get them into shape.  We have tools to deal with bad answers regardless of the question class under consideration.

Comment: I'm not talking about classes of question either.

Comment: Hmm, then maybe we just agree.  *crinkles eyebrows*  upon inspecting other points I see *and so poor quality homebrew questions are often primarily opinion-based. These should be closed while the asker is helped to refine the question* I find my self in agreement with you.

Comment: Then I don't know what purpose the "concrete/abstract" quotation has here, as in context I could only understand it to be saying that questions shouldn't be closed if *some* people can read between the lines to intuit what the querent *meant* to be asking. (And this is in line with some of your own statements about not closing questions that haven't been fixed if the fix is  --to you-- sufficiently obvious.) Your statements here seem to imply that there's *never* a good reason to close a homebrew question as too opinion-based, & all I'm saying is that any class of question can be asked poorly.

Comment: @BESW On that we certainly agree: *any class of question can be asked poorly*  I stumbled across a circa 2015 meta on homebrew earlier today while looking for something else.  When I finish that particular project, I'll revisit that meta and see if I can glean a kernel of how the general brain trust assessed the state of play at that point in time.  It may be helpful to this line of inquiry.

Comment: @BESW After reviewing your comment again, the parantheses bit is intended to point toward tapping into experience base as a resource; to infer from my input that there's never a good reason to close a homebrew question as opinion based is not even close to my position.  (Recently engaged with FenrisG on one that is just to big, too broad, and too brainstormy).  Some are too big, too badly organized, to (feature) and so on.

Comment: I am [referring to this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123894/22566), but there are a few others from the last week that had to be closed/stay closed as the ability (or desire?) to tighten the scope wasn't there.  It is nice to see the positive engagement regardless of  the ultimate ability to fit within the limits/constraints.   There are still plenty of questions like that which may need to get brainstormed in chat, or at a forum.

Comment: Then I'm glad I was able to call to your attention the fact that your post implies, by a glaring absence, something that isn't at all close to your position.

Comment: @BESW What would you recommend as an edit to address that?

Comment: Almost a year out, how do you think it's going?

Comment: @nitsua60 just saw this, give me a bit to digest and respond

Comment: @nitsua60 we have more of them, and they all take a lot of work.  Or so it seems.  The one I asked got good and helpful answers.

Answer (score 26):

### We are thriving!

Post counts per month are at an all-time high - March 2018 was the most active month in the site's history! ([ugly Data engine query](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/revision/752104/1042804/posts-per-month) for posts-per-month)

The popularity of this site is clearly ramping up in long-term. While increasing traffic occasionally brings forth new needs for moderation (such as the hot topic of [designer reasons](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7914/how-do-we-save-designer-reasoning-questions)), overall I see the increased traffic as a healthy sign of the relatively rigid format of the Stack (compared to the more "noisy" forums) gaining traction and acceptance among the RPG communities around the world.

Comment: Internal analytics confirm this March just passed is our most active month ever in terms of either questions or answers or both combined.

Answer (score 26):

## I'd like to see less answering in the comments

#### Current status

There are too many answers in the comments. Not only from new users but experienced ones as well. The only metric I have to quantify this is my own flag history, but I have flagged 16 comment answers this month alone which seems like a lot to me.

New users are understandable especially because other stacks have different enforcement policies. However, I've seen a surprising amount of this from experienced (and sometimes very experienced) users. This may mean that the community is not in agreement about the comment policy or that we are failing to educate even experienced members. In at least one case a comment answer from an experienced user was at least partially responsible for derailing attempts to fix/answer a question completely.

Note that this is the only stack site that I frequent, so if this actually really good then that is fine, but I think we can do better.

#### Suggestion - comment when deleting/flagging

Aside from the obvious things we should already be doing (not answering in the comments, flagging answers in comments aggressively) I do have a proposal that I think might be useful.

I think that we should try to always leave a comment when we remove a comment answer. I know we *do* do this, but I don't think we do it enough.

The reason I say this something we should be doing more is that as a new user this was exactly the way I learned how to behave. Seeing "comments are not for extended discussion" and "don't comment in the answers" comments in a lot of places is what helped me learn what is accepted in the community without having to make those mistakes myself first. It makes sense that this could be the case for other users as well.

Additionally, if the comment tags the person, they know that their comment was removed and why and hopefully won't do it again. This is helpful in cases where the person just leaves a comment then never reads the question again.

And, to be clear, this is something that every person in the community that has the rep to comment can and should be doing. This is not the sole responsibility of diamond moderators.

**tl;dr** When you (yes you) see an answer in the comments, flag it then comment saying that it goes against our policy. Doing so should create a greater awareness of the policy for new and experienced users alike.

*This answer is now part of an answer to this question: [What to do about comment misuse?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7937/what-to-do-about-comment-misuse)*

Comment: Maybe I’m looking at different questions, but honestly, it seems to me that RPG does far, far better with this than most Stacks.

Comment: @KRyan I know that different stacks treat comments very differently, so I  have no doubt that there are others that are worse. I'm not even saying that we are *bad* necessarily, just that I think we can do better.

Comment: There's an experiment running on Interpersonal related to this and other comment misuses: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2839/3556

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Yep. Sometimes it seems like people who post an answer then run to another answer's comments just to campaign for their own answer's superiority. I think I was guilty of this a couple times until I noticed how unhelpful it is. Generally, it seems like answer comments are worse when they come from the poster of another answer.

Comment: This would definitely help :) If the increase in site traffic from [kviiri's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7927/23064) is any indication, we have had a surge of new users that need to know this. Interestingly, this is the opposite of last year's [We don't comment-answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6915/23064) post, but I'm sure it will go back to normal

Comment: I do agree, there’s been a recent uptick in answers in comments.  I delete then when I see them  or they are flagged, but it seems like I’ve had to do that more in the last 3 months than in the 9 preceding.

Comment: Let's take this one to [What to do about comment misuse?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7937/what-to-do-about-comment-misuse)

Comment: I don't know if this site is better at avoiding it in the first place than other SE sites, but it does seem like the mods are more on top of it here - and for that I am thankful.

Comment: @V2Blast We RPG.se mods are unusually militant about that particular part of the [comment help page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), definitely. I (obviously!) think it's a good thing, but it's good to hear some feedback that it's appreciated. Too often we only hear the feedback from surprised/unhappy users who just had a comment removed. :)

Comment: I'm really glad that, even though we are leaps and bounds better than other stacks at this, we still seek to improve. I just went on a quick tour through several other stacks, and _every_ question that could be answered with a simple yes or no had such an answer in the comments. That's not something I see as often here.

Comment: This is better than for example stackoverflow, where most answers are in the comments for fear of downvotes.

Answer (score 20):

## It feels like comments have gotten more argumentative.

When I first began posting answers on this site, I enjoyed it a lot. The last few months, I have not enjoyed it, so I've stopped answering for anything but the most trivial questions, even though I visit and read every day. This is my own perception, but I feel like comments on my answers and other people's answers have a disproportionately high number of unhelpful arguments in them now. I would call it trolling, and although I might be alone in calling it that, I see it affecting other people besides just myself.

I understand the need for comments that help to improve answers by pointing out ambiguities or weak areas to be edited, and I appreciate them and I try to incorporate genuinely helpful suggestions whenever I can, or I politely decline if I disagree. I try to do the same in turn. All of that works well. However, it feels like whenever I post an answer now, I expect a couple of those helpful comments... plus a slew of comments from people who will argue with my answer no matter how many times I may revise or reword troublesome sections or explain what it's actually saying.

Often the arguments are from those who posted different answers and could be summarized as "your answer is not correct because mine is correct instead." I'm uninterested in talking specific occurrences or culprits, but it's usually the same individuals, and every time I see their usernames show up in the comments for my answers or other people's answers I know I'm in for an unnecessary argument, as if I were on a forum and not SE. It's usually about red herrings, unrelated questions, straw-man interpretations of my actual answer, and misunderstandings of how English or first-order predicate logic works.

Sometimes this trolling has continued to happen even after word-of-god from a designer confirmed that my answer was correct and the querent accepted my answer as correct/helpful for them. I've actually been told my answer is ridiculous *after* adding in a designer quote and having my answer accepted as correct. A lot of times it feels like they're arguing with me about my answer because they actually disapprove of the paradigm or designer intent that informs the answer, not my reasoning. It strikes me as the "badwrongfun" that I've heard about, or in general a sort of "badwrongthink."

Basically, I find answering stressful anymore because of a handful of people with very unhelpful behavior on this site. It's possible my stressed reaction is not shared by others, but I doubt I'm the only one less inclined to post due to perceived trolling behavior. The comments on RPG.SE look a lot more like the comments on YouTube or Tumblr now, and that's discouraging.

Even posting this meta is stressful because now I'm expecting to be lambasted for being too touchy or sensitive or something. However, the vast majority of RPG.SE users are respectful and helpful with their comments and have genuinely helped me to improve my answer-writing skills and online-anonymous-interpersonal-communication skills, and for that I thank them.

Comment: Thanks, this does totally happen. FWIW: You are not obligated to action every request a commenter might make. You may feel free to flag comments for removal, including suggesting it's time to nuke the thread or move it to chat. If there are requests you're uninterested in actioning, those can go as well. Reading your second-to-last paragraph: would you take it that many of these comments are violating our goal to [embrace a plurality of playstyles](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/can-we-affirm-that-rpg-se-embraces-a-plurality-of-playstyles)?

Comment: While I have spent a lot of years advising people on the internet "grow a thicker skin" I've been sensing what you've been seeing, so I am glad that you have brought this up.  (And if I have been a contributor to your unease, I do write a lot of comments, my apologies).

Comment: I'll add to greener's note: please feel free when flagging to use the custom text to say "this person's been arguing a lot with my posts." It can be really helpful for us (elected moderators) to have pointers like that so that we can address a *person* (if needed), not just a particular comment.

Comment: Upvote for you on this...and I hope I'm not one of the users who comes across like that. I know I do question answers and ask for clarifications, but I hope I don't do it in the way you're talking about.

Comment: @doppelgreener It's sometimes but not always about playstyle conflict, I think, but usually just about other people's refusal to acknowledge that several answers can be logically valid and consistent without agreeing with each other.

Comment: More often than not the comment threads devolve into straw-man arguments, where I'm accused of claiming something that is neither stated nor implied by my answer. After I point out that that is not the case several times, make reasonable revisions, and am still accused of saying things I didn't say, I get frustrated and complain that the comments are not actually helpful or trying to improve the answer, and then I get victim-blamed about that. I've not seen this behavior from anybody who has commented on this, nor have I seen it in a moderation-specific capacity.

Comment: @Bloodcinder Thank you. That definitely sounds like a realm of commenting we'd be interested in seeing flagged for removal. You don't have to justify your answer to everyone who might want it justified to them, and you definitely don't have to go as far as it sounds like you've been going. Sorry to hear you've been put through hassles like that.

Comment: I mean, I have as much of an ego as anybody else, I guess. Egos are pretty strong among GM's, and maybe they have to be. However, I teach propositional and predicate logic, so I consider myself capable of forming a consistent and valid argument, pending minor revisions, and I also can put aside personal opinions and preferences to appreciate a logically valid argument that starts with different hypotheses than mine happens to. As a teacher, I hate seeing bad logic from student work, and when I'm accused of bad logic that is not actually there... I guess I can't help but be troll-baited.

Comment: @nitsua60 I'll try to remember that. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Bloodcinder I completely agree. Strawman arguments are really frustrating to me and I have a very hard time not arguing against them (on my posts) because of the fact that someone else is misrepresenting what I am saying. And, even worse, often in a way that is intended to undermine my argument. As others have said, I hope I was not among those contributing to your issue. I've tried very hard to improve my commenting habits.

Comment: You haven't been. The misrepresentation you mention is really frustrating, that's the major source of stress. However, the vast majority of RPG.SE users are respectful and helpful with their comments and have genuinely helped me to improve my answer-writing skills and online-anonymous-interpersonal-communication skills.

Comment: Also I feel like [this comment](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/how-is-the-community-doing-2018/7930?noredirect=1#comment25118_7930) that @doppelgreener left on my answer is very relevant here as well: "There's an experiment running on Interpersonal related to this and other comment misuses: [interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2839/3556](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2839/3556)"

Comment: Yeah, this seems to happen a lot.  For me it seems to come up with a couple of specific users, and I very much agree it has to do with the badwrongthink thing, though I suspect they probably feel the same about me in reverse.  From experience, flagging the comments and not engaging is a good idea, but it's hard to not engage...  Also it makes answering weird cause it seems like answers come in packs with backing from certain playstyles most of the time, and the playstyle that answers first 'wins' the thread via this process.  It's not quite that bad, yet, but it's definitely getting there :/

Comment: I agree.  It seems to me like we'd gotten comment threads down to a reasonable level, and then it started shooting up.  And it's not because the community isn't helping, there's more comment-flags-per-day than there used to be (I don't have metrics on that, but seems like).  I think maybe we need a separate focused meta on cracking down on comment misuse given this answer and some of the others.

Comment: I wonder, as someone who hasn’t played much of 5e and hasn’t spent a lot of time looking at those questions and answers, if this might be due to... not *new* users, but, say, “sophomore” users, in that space? Because I haven’t seen as much of this as I used to (...as I certainly have done myself in the past.... hopefully just in the past... well, hopefully *mostly* in the past), which might be a sign of some maturity (maybe) in other question spaces? So I wonder if the “shooting up” that @mxyzplk mentions is related to 5e’s age on this site?

Comment: It's possible, because I pretty much only monitor 5e and a handful of games that nobody posts for (13th Age, for example), so I wouldn't have experienced the issue in other spaces. But I might go further and say that often it seems like the people who are causing the problem I perceive in the 5e space look like they are pre-5e grognards who are trying to grognard about 5e. That's _purely conjecture_ on my part. I have _no_ evidence of that, but that's how it feels. Coming from a 3.5e/d20 background myself, I can recognize some of that paradigm-superiority-ism bleeding through.

Comment: Well, there's noob to gaming and noob to SE.  I do think a lot of the answering in comments, and to a lesser degree arguing in comments, is people newer to the site, though they may be gaming grognards.   For AoC there's a little bit of "old site hardcases" (longer tenure/higher rep) who seem to just not care that their  comment answers will be deleted, but arguing tends to be newer folks because over time we've been more forward with warnings/suspensions about that so generally there folks don't do it after having been here a bit.

Comment: Let's take this one to https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7937/what-to-do-about-comment-misuse

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's correlated with D&D 5e somehow. There's a lot of push-pull tension around this edition because it purports to be the “embrace all playstyles” edition, but there's official statements and grognards and new players and RAW players and a bunch of different groups' approaches all pulling in different directions as to what is “correct”. And of course, SE emphasises a certain subset of varieties of correctness, too. 5e has felt like a bit of a powder keg, playstyle-wise, on RPG.se.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Does that mean that RPG-citizens are not embracing the whole spectrum of playstyles in their 5e centric activity?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I meant that the format of the site favours certain types of questions and answers over others. For an extreme example, the “follow me while I muse creatively on the subject” types of posts common — and productive! — on forums and blogs are a variety of “correctness” extremely discouraged by the way the site works.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie OK, it was the last sentence that prompted my comment/question.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Oh I see. I wouldn't say that citizens aren't embracing the whole spectrum, so much as that the friction inherent in D&D 5e's simultaneous embrace of all playstyles while seeming to say “but really *this* is the right way” is just begging for sparks. In other words, I blame 5e for tempting people to argue. :) That we haven't often seen that powder keg lit is actually encouraging.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Copy all, and I do now and again pull in a link to Crawford's "RAW/RAI/RAF" thoughts .... though I am not sure how often that helps.

Comment: Getting late to the party. I have been through this a lot as well. (I might be part of the problem, as I'm unable to simply flag a not-helpful comment and end up arguing as well). My main problem are comments that keep saying "I think you are wrong, your reading is wrong". Usually when I lose patience I end up saying "Comments are not for discussing. If you feel you have a better answer, please go ahead and post it. If you want to discuss, ping me in the chat".

Comment: As my part of the guilt, I think I did something similar to @KorvinStarmast recently. As I tried to explain there, though, it's mostly because I ask for clarification in a very "affirmative" way. :P Sorry for him and anyone else who got annoyed by that, I'm trying to word this kind of comment in a more question-like way.

Comment: @HellSaint not to worry, I think we sorted it out eventually (maybe in chat) to clear up the misunderstanding.  Chat's handy that way.

Answer (score 19):

### This stack is run as a tight ship — thank all the gods!

I'm a little bit more immersed in Stack Exchange culture than I was last time one of these threads rolled around, and I've had the chance to spend some time looking at how things are done on other stacks.  One thing that's struck me is how *well* this stack implements the "we're a Q&A site, let's optimize for useful questions with useful answers" approach.

There are other answers here lamenting [answers-in-comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/how-is-the-community-doing-2018/7930#7930) and [argumentative comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7931/30299), and no doubt these are genuinely areas where we can improve.  But on the other hand, guys...have you *been* to other stacks?  It took me a while to realize this, but we are *so good* at this stuff.  Our comment sections could look like Worldbuilding.SE (once [aptly described](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2636) by our very own nitsua60 as "a lightly-threaded brainstorming site") or Interpersonal.SE (the poster-child for "how far can we push the boundaries of the Q&A model").

Instead, the SE model here is *working*.  People ask questions.  They almost always get answers (our list of unanswered questions is [tiny](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/unanswered)).  Most of the answers don't suck.  Problematic content quickly gets closed/flagged/downvoted/commented with suggestions for improvement.  The review queue practically never has more than maybe five items in it.

And it's not like this site *couldn't* have gone the other way.  I imagine most folks here are (or have been) active on at least one other RPG-centric online community.  We *know* the kind of discussion that's typical in the arguing-about-RPGs-verse.  Whatever bumps it's hit along the way, this place deserves credit for becoming a functional, Q&A-focused stack, instead of just one more place to get in a shouting match about whether Monks are decent this week.

Good job!

Comment: I wasn't around here last year, but the fact that RPG.SE keeps me coming back regularly definitely seems to support the assertion that it's run well! And I can agree that people stay well on top of the review queue... there's rarely anything for me to review :)

Comment: Hmm. I rather prefer the style of Worldbuilding to RPG.SE, myself. I find RPG.SE terribly stifling to my own and others' expression, and the moderation and other limits keep me from participating except in the few cases where the stars align to create an opening for appropriate participation. Just saying.

Answer (score 17):

## We suck at not answering questions, especially in popular tags

Good questions often don't have easy answers.  Officially, you're allowed to post a question within our scope whose answer would, at least theoretically, fit well within our format, yet which is in practice unlikely to be answered because of how difficult it is to answer/how few people have the required experience.  For example, it is officially *totally okay* to ask a question about the best way to handle a specific technically complex mechanic in an obscure not-digitally-available rule system and require/expect a competent answer-- I might ask "When calculating fire trajectories in *Phoenix Command*, how can I best do it quickly?".  In practice, such questions draw really terrible answers that get upvoted and deleting them just makes more get posted: our site hates to see questions unanswered and our site community on some level believes a *bad* answer is better than *no* answer, which is both wrong and against the SE corporate paradigm.

Let's take the example Phoenix Command question.  Questions for obscure rule systems fare *much* better in terms of this particular problem, but I *actually did* post [this not-nearly-as-complicated Phoenix Command question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101444/what-book-contains-the-rules-for-riot-shields) and, as you can see (10k only), it got a terrible answer.  It's been okay since then, I think mostly cause it's an obscure rule system with no popular tags and an *extremely* not-subjective, not-advice-seeking category of question ('Is X content in Y book or not?'), but it still demonstrates the point.  If a question isn't posted on quickly, people start posting terrible stuff in an attempt to help.  These answers will often admit in their preamble that they are not real answers, saying something like "I've never played that game you're talking about, but here's my gut reaction anyways" or "I've never run that module, but why don't you XYZ?"

I think the users doing this don't see the difference between that and "I haven't ever [X], but I've [X'] extensively, and here's why I think that is relevant", which is a form often used in good answers to difficult questions.

Personally, I think this is one of the major factors leading to designer-reason questions going badly (the other being querents being steered into asking said questions to skirt site rules when what they really want is not allowed), but that's a separate conversation.

Comment: This is where I certainly rely on the community to go ahead and use downvotes and flags, too.

Comment: I definitely agree, and I think the problem extends to people jumping to answer poorly posed or otherwise unclear questions too. I suspect that the underlying reason is that we keep upvoting answers that don't deserve upvotes, which means that people posting bad answers still usually get net positive reputation.

Comment: @Icyfire Yes, this is absolutely the core problem, but fixing it requires a culture shift and in a direction contrary to our inertia, at least in my understanding of the situation.

Comment: I feel like it's not just that they're rewarded with votes. There's a sibling relationship between comments in answers and “I must fill this blank space” answers-in-answers: both are frequently born from the feeling that *trying to help* is better than nothing at all. (Removing answer-comments, especially on held Qs, often earns the complaint that we should “just help” them, missing the point.) I am concerned that there will always be people who miss the point of the blank answer box, and the site as a whole, and will take the invitation to post useless answers that are “better than nothing”.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, but when those answers are downvoted, even just enough that they end up with negative scores, they don't look like correct use of the site to the next visitor to come along.  When they are consistently upvoted enough to have positive scores it sends the message that the site thinks this behavior is good, even if the leadership of the site thinks otherwise, which leads to the new people participating regularly in the site being more people who want to participate in a site that behaves that way and less people who oppose such thinking, which moves de-facto site policy slowly

Comment: Right! Yes, that is a good point and I realise now I should have said so. Downvoting the well-meaning but misguided answers is very valuable. I don’t think it will ever eliminate those, but I do think it’s important to do so and I do think it will reduce them. Thanks for poking me so I realise I missed my message. :)

Answer (score 15):

#### New User Experience [remains a problem](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/869/site-approachability); it's never been solved

And maybe it can't be solved<sup>2</sup>.  It's so easy to hide behind "this is now SE works" and "this site's not for everybody" attitude<sup>3</sup> that comes from the top.  The extended discussion under various answers in the linked question in this title made SE/SO top level leadership's view on this abundantly clear.  The response to one of our most experienced users captures the attitude in a nutshell:

> ... it is very unwelcoming to have your first efforts be shut down, to have to read all of meta and then all of the SE blog to figure out what the {censored}'s off topic or an acceptable answer ... (@[mxyzplk, from a comment under the linked question/answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/869/site-approachability/873#comment1771_873))

Reply

> @mxy well, our traffic graph data respectfully chooses to disagree with your opinion. :)  (@[JeffAtwood](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/869/site-approachability/873#comment1774_873))

The discussion in more detail is under the linked question in the title. The reason that I included this specific bit, rather than other stuff from that extended discussion, is to illustrate that what comes off now and again as RPG.SE being "tone deaf" to new user disorientation starts at the top and isn't new.  (The motorcycle analogy further down in that meta might be more apt as an example ... and I've been advised that some of the top leadership has since changed ...)

How do I know that it's easy to fall into the trap of contributing to barriers to the new user experience?  Because I've done it myself ... and I've even [defended it](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6114/24204) on a [different SE](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6122/24204).

A variety of users have expressed frustration with barriers to new users.
[Common new user experience observation](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/new-user-experience-why-allow-downvotes-esp-below-0-on-already-closed-questi#comment5649_2979)

#### Why this Answer?

As I've discovered over the three years of participating here, there is a limited set of ways to ask a question that won't get it closed, and **it's not uncommon for new users to not yet have figured that out.**

#### What needs to change

Each new user needs to be treated as a person, not as a name connected to a question that may or may not meet our usually accepted style of how to ask a question.  Add to that the fact that *not all of our new question askers are working in their native language* and I will assert that helping new users is the better initial response for that case as well, rather than hoping that maybe a given new user will "get" how SE works as their initial offering is characterized as somehow not up to RPG.SE standards.

I was encouraged during some chat to raise this in on meta, after having reached my limit of frustration with [the responses to new users during the early phase of this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124040/22566).  After three years of watching new users get this kind of treatment too often, I am no longer willing to just put up with it.  This question is a single example of a long running pattern that I've seen since I first began to participate three years ago.

- Scenario: a brand new user and brand new DM asked about "How should this work?" in the LMoP published adventure where she ran into a knotty problem.

  This was an opportunity for the body of experience based expertise resident at RPG.SE to provide a helpful answer to this problem.

  I (1) noticed a few spoilers and (2) a method of phrasing that was likely going to get the knee jerk "close as opinion based" responses that often crop up with first time question askers.

  What I did was edit the question to add two spoilers, and to adjust the phrasing to something closer to an answerable form than was originally offered by our new user.  **This person can't be expected to be familiar with our informal style guide.**  I then left a comment letting them know what I had done, welcoming them to the site, and offering a suggestion for a site search on some related questions that might address stuff related to that published adventure.

  Here is what I see as the core problem: while I was doing the above, and before I finished the edit in an effort to positively engage with and help a new user, I noticed that the standard lazy response arrived: drive by close vote, with no comment.  (I know how this works, this lazy drive by close vote, since I know that I am guilty of having done that in the past when going through the review queue).

  A later close vote at least included a comment that a DM question is an opinion based question (that's since been resolved via the usual process and the question got reopened); what made the response more negative in my view was that it was not **helpful** to a new user, and as it worked out it wasn't even right.  (Another user in a comment under the question pointed to a meta on why that reason to close wasn't suitable to this question).

  The straw that broke the camel's back for me was how that *attitude* is not helpful to a **new user**, but at least the commenter had the courtesy to explain what was behind *one* of the close votes.

  - Please note: that comment would not be an issue for **an experienced user**.  Once any of us gets used to this site's tone, style, limitations and nature, the various styles and flavors of response become familiar and are far less likely to be annoying or off-putting. We already feel welcome enough to participate.

#### Repeated For Emphasis: this answer is about the new user experience only

No other topic is relevant to this answer.

This response to "how are we doing" is (1) rooted in the negative experience I received in first interacting on this site, is (2) a small subset of [a larger SE/SO tone problem that is finally getting addressed by SE's current overlords](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/), and (3) is a standing problem on this SE that was explicitly labeled by Brian Ballson-Stanton (a former diamond mod) as a problem with [How Approachable This Site Is To New Users](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/869/site-approachability).
As an unsolved problem, it's at least six years old for this SE.

#### Experiential point

Making a first impression can be done well, but too often on this site it is done poorly. (See above example, and below I offer you an example of a good one).  Were it not the fact that I am stubborn, I'd not have returned to this site after my firsts few interactions with people responding to this new user.  <sub>Being me, I returned fire on what I felt was a cheap shot in comments, and I got some feedback from a mod on along the lines of "let's not do that flame war in comments thing." Thanks to @SSD for that</sub> 
RPG.SE made a lousy first impression on me.
 <sub>Getting hostile and rude comments under answers from experienced users like @Dyndrilliac and @KRyan didn't help, but we already have an answer to this meta on on garbage in comments; I won't digress further and I have since made peace with @KRyan</sub>

RPG.SE has also made a poor first impression on a variety of experienced SE users, not just new users to SE's system (this was my first SE).  I'll use [Conduit's point as an example](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7066/22566); over the last 3 years, TuggyNE, nvoigt, and some others who are stack experienced have sounded off in a similar vein, each with their own concerns.  Some of the other answers to this Meta Question [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6922/22566), [and here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7950/22566), [and here too](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7958/22566) look very much like the are addressing symptoms of what is the same problem.  [This question reflects a similar level of frustration with overall site tone, but it may not be a good fit for the new user issue.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8027/22566)

#### OK, Korvin, you see a problem: what do I do about it?

In response to @mxy's encouragement for actionable items: **you do three things**.

1. When a new user (150 rep or lower to account for cross-stack movement) asks a question, *before you do anything else* you click on their profile and see **who** it is.  Remember that you are responding to a user, a person, not to a question.  When I started doing that, I stopped doing the drive by during my community moderation actions in the review queue.
2. Do it like @DuckTapeAl

   If you want an example of how to do it right, look at these two comments that Al left for a new user.

   [Would love some feedback and answers; Physically blind pc but uses 3rd eye and chakras to see the environment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124079/would-love-some-feedback-and-answers-physically-blind-pc-but-uses-3rd-eye-and-c#comment306465_124079)

   [Would love some feedback and answers; Physically blind pc but uses 3rd eye and chakras to see the environment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124079/would-love-some-feedback-and-answers-physically-blind-pc-but-uses-3rd-eye-and-c#comment306463_124079)

   That's a fantastic example of how to treat a new user well; thanks to @DuckTapeAl.  Another user here who sets a superb example is @HeyICanChan.

   "But that's more work for me ..."
3. Yes, you are right, it's more work for you and **our new users are worth that little bit of effort to treat them like a person, rather than to treat their input as the question** (which is not a person)

---

#### A brief bibliography of things that ...

having read a while back, I had to go and find again<sup>2</sup>

[scaring off new users](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/964/22566), 
[even experienced users get put off by tone](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4803/22566), 
[other SE user sees RPG.SE behavior as an outlier](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1163/asking-for-advice-looking-forward-to-answers-questions-closed-now-disillusion#comment11358_4803), 
[New User Experience obstacles](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1163/asking-for-advice-looking-forward-to-answers-questions-closed-now-disillusion#comment11362_4803), 
[New users addressed here, but maybe nobody bothers reading that far back, and some of the response looks like a case of newbie unfriendly as a norm being accepted](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1591/22566), 
[A diamond mod makes an appeal for eltism because SE is meant to be about experts](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1594/22566), {Note: this might have been before the diamond in this case, and I generally appreciated waxy's modding} ... [Comments under this answer send signals easily received as “newbie unfriendly” even if not so intended](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1621/22566), [One a number of unhappy new users](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2690/22566), 
[problems with how newcomers get treated 2015 version](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5814/22566), [Dogpiling new users with downvotes is OK](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2971/22566)
[Common new user experience observation](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/new-user-experience-why-allow-downvotes-esp-below-0-on-already-closed-questi#comment5649_2979)
Which takes us into the time frame where I began to participate in some meta discussions.
[insular tight knit community](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3171/22566), {which from the inside looks good, and from the outside looks unwelcoming, **particularly to new users**}
[Users from other SE’s surprised by RPG.SE norms](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3170/22566)
[Rude in general, and to new users specfifically](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3512/22566)
[**it isn’t just me who sees this**](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4816/22566)
I am going to make a note here: I have in a number of conversations, with other users and with mods, applied my own term/neologism for this received rudeness, this atmosphere. I will now call it *inherent hostility*: I firmly believe that it is a byproduct of the format far more than any intentional stance by vast majority of users on this SE.  I’ll break that term down here.
*inherent* in that it exists within the machine/organism and is part of it due to how the machine is built
*hostility* being *how it is received* with some frequency by new users.
It is certainly what I received on arrival, even if nobody intended to be mean.
How to mitigate inherent hostility?  Mitigation can only be procedural (you can't remove the heart without killing off the patient).
I believe that **the three steps proposed in my answer above** will act as useful mitigation so that *new users are less likely to experience that*.

---

<sup>3</sup>  [... the structural hostility is a founding principle of all parts of the site design](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/how-is-the-community-doing-2018/8069?noredirect=1#comment25752_8069).

Comment: Thank you for posting this.

Comment: @doppelgreener I still have misgivings ... but thankfully I tripped over ducktapeal's comments as I was mulling this over and realized I'd been given a gift of a great example ...  I have about six things that need to be edited, and I can't right  now due to browser/SE conflict thing.  Will revisit in a bit.

Comment: What you’re describing is “***structural*** hostility”. “Latent” is simply the wrong word for what you’re asserting (“existing but not yet developed or manifested”), and you’re getting disapproval because “latent” hostility can only manifest by someone taking it & developing it into obvious (ie., banned) hostility. In the social sciences, the word for what you’re describing is “structural”. Unless you *mean* to say that we as a community have a store of secret hostility that we choose to suddenly reveal to ambush people with, I suggest using the word that matches what you’ve described instead.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie what about inherent/  Structural doesn't capture what I am trying to articulate.  I will also point to the [problem of SE being an engine not a community, as expressed by you and waxy here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5132/22566), such that it enables an impersonal response that is *received as hostile*, rather than intentionally sent as hostile.  It's my neologism, and I'm keeping it until I get something better.  So far, not better, but I do appreciate the offer.

Comment: It's the system's lurking feature, not any given user's feature.  An experienced user will not see the same thing as a new user.  I'll try other synonyms later.  You are reading into the term something that isn't there, and as I had offered to you before, that term comes to me from editing technical manuals and the latent errors therein.  I don't want to use structural because to me that implies an intended design element, rather than a byproduct of a design.

Comment: You may stand by your neologism, but we expect people to say what they mean and mean what they say, so as we have previously told you, you are not welcome to accuse the community of latent hostility, and you’re familiar with how we enforce that. Please reconsider.

Comment: Aside, you would be right, the site is **structurally** hostile… but only to a subset of new users, and by design. They’re incompatible with the site, and the structural hostility is a founding principle of all parts of the site design. We have to filter out those who cannot or will not agree with the SE system. Those who are incompatible are vocal disproportionately to their percentage though, so it’s important to not commit an [availability heiristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Availability_heuristic) error and overestimate how many people in the whole population are affected/turned away.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Since you are overwriting your opinion into my attempt at an explanation, that is not appreciated at all.  There  may be another term (and inherent  may be it) but your accusation that I am accusing the community of being hostile is utterly false, as I explained now twice, and once before.  In fact, the problem with naming this is that I am pretty sure that in the vast majority of the cases, only one end of the message (receiving) sees hostile, as the sender isn't trying to be mean.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie This is rather frustrating; I am in good faith trying to explain as clearly as I can what I mean, and you threaten me.  When I told dopple and BESW that I have no faith in the meta process, your latest comment is the kind of response I was referring to.  Can we please not do this?  I'd rather not this answer to the meta, which two mods encouraged me to write, have been an utter waste of time.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast To clarify: you've defined it here, which prevents misunderstanding *here*. But if you're going to use “latent hostility” as a shortcut without explanation elsewhere — the usual purpose of coining a neologism — it won't get any special interpretation from mods and will be moderated according to its usual meaning, as that is the meaning it will be contributing to discussion.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The whole reason I put that there was so that what I mean is clear.  I am good with workshopping it, and at the moment "received hostility" is beginning to bubble up as perhaps clearer and more descriptive ... I'll think on it.  There may be an even better term.  Beyond that, your second comment, that hostility to newbies is intended (really?) is to me a different sort of problem because that seems to me to be self defeating.  It's kind of surreal for me to explain to you what I mean, only to have you tell me "no, you mean this."  Can you appreciate how it looks from my shoes?

Comment: The observation that the site contains structural hostility is good — it's good to finally recognise it — but it's not new. It's a [founding principle](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) of Stack Exchange. All the closes, holds, locks, reputation ladders, and everything else derives from that basic core principle that not everyone is interested in helping this engine run, and those who are against this engine need to be incentivised to neither try to change the engine, nor to throw sand in its gears. Objecting that the site uses its immune system is futile.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That does not change the fact that new users being treated badly doesn't have to happen, even with the constraints of the system as stated.  Do you disagree with the three points I present as mitigation?

Comment: I disagree with (1) and (3) because they misunderstand the point of RPG.se—we are not supposed to treat questions as people, we are to treat them as questions. The decades-long goal of RPG.se is to curate good answers to questions. Helping people is the method, not the goal, of getting a good database of posts. (This is also all deliberate founding principles.) We are supposed to treat all questions equally, regardless of the name under them. (There's a reason the name is *under* posts, not over like on many discussion forums.) I agree with (2) but only because it's good question curation.

Comment: So if we can be welcoming without sacrificing the whole point of the site, then we do. When welcoming methods conflict with the goal, those methods are not acceptable (which is why we will never not-close questions just to make people feel better about it).

Comment: Your disagreement with 3 puzzles me, given the effort I've seen you make to offer assistance in hundreds of cases to users all over the site.  I confess, my head is now being scratched.

Comment: All my efforts to help users has been to guide them into being constructive contributors to the purpose of the site. If they don't want that, or can't be, I'm quick to put out the barriers and site-protective spikes. We've lost high-rep users because they came into conflict with the goals of the site, and refused to adjust. That's as it should be.

Comment: This Isn't About A Question Being Closed.  I still do VTC's.  This is (1) the drive by treatment of a new user (old  users, this  isn't a problem) and (2) the attitude behind the drive by.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Being dismissive or looking down on new users is bad for the site because it throws sand in the gears — if people are going to engage with a question, then they should take the time to do it right and constructively, or leave it to someone who can. In that, the outcome of good question-curation and being friendly happen to coincide. But it's very important to recognise the goal isn't to be friendly for friendliness' sake; when good site management and friendliness conflict (and they do), then friendliness mustn't override what we're supposed to do.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am using "inherent" as a placeholder for the time being.  Will cogitate further.

Comment: Alright. I'm still concerned there's potential miscommunication there, but it's definitely better than the people-centric implications of “latent”. Cheers. I think I understand much better where you're coming from; hopefully we've both learned some things.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The problem I have [with this comment](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/how-is-the-community-doing-2018/8069?noredirect=1#comment25747_8069) is that you were not addressing the news users as a whole, but rather a small subset of new users who speak up.  My objective in writing this answer is to address the hostility that any  new user will receive that is preventable; it takes us a little time, I think, to clearly perceive who simply won't be a good fit.  Again, even experienced SE users are seeing a barrier; these are people who 'get' the SE system.

Comment: @Korvin I can see that objection… But, I deliberately wasn’t addressing every new user. The point of many of the mechanisms of the site is to reduce workload on the community, new user vetting included. New users are meant to be vetted automatically, **self**-sorting according to their personal journey adapting to the site, naturally matching it from the beginning, failing to adapt to the site, or naturally clashing with it. We’re not supposed to be manually overriding that process — that interferes with its efficacy at naturally selecting fitting users and filtering out those who don’t fit.

Comment: In other words, the barrier you and others are perceiving was put there on purpose; it’s an obstacle course shaped to pass those who suit the site and fail those who don’t. So saying “there’s a barrier!” isn’t a call to action that will inspire fixing it. We aren’t unaware of it. That’s just saying “there’s a moat and walls around the castle”: yes, we put them there. Crossing them may be inconvenient, but the alternative is the castle burning down some day, by accident or intentionally. We’re charged with keeping the moat filled and the walls and gates in repair and functioning as designed.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It is not necessary to be dismissive and hostile to *all* new users in order to deal with the small category of new users who won't/don't fit  well here.  (I pay attention.  There is indeed a class of users who are not a good fit here: protonflux is not the only one who admitted as much in one of his last comments).  **That's the message**.   Your message to me is that it is OK to be hostile to all new users on the outside chance that any new user might become a problem.  (And if you really feel that way, I'll once again to confess to scratching my head).

Comment: This is where your distinction between structural hostility and human-generated hostility is critical to keep in mind. The site’s mechanisms and rules are structurally hostile. The site is sink-or-swim by design. However, we as humans need not — should not — communicate with new users in a hostile way. We should communicate hospitably, I agree. The distinction I am drawing is that the obligation to communication hospitably (Be Nice rule) is separate from the site’s mechanical/rule hostility. The structural hostility must not be mitigated; the communication hospitability is good but separate.

Comment: We see people advocating for less structural hostility all the time — close slower, allow answers in comments, allow discussion, allow opinion-based questions — in the name of being more friendly, and thus showing misunderstanding of the point of the site’s rules/mechanisms. So making this distinction clear is critically important to get on the same page in site friendliness discussions. We as a community can’t afford to endorse positions that don’t recognise the value of the moat.

Comment: This answer pervasively advocates undermining the core mechanisms and barriers of the site, woven together with otherwise-good pleas to be more kind. That conflation makes it a non-starter — mods can’t get on board with this, without violating the mission we (literally) signed onto when we were made mods.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie My 3 suggestions are aimed at addressing inhospitable personal responses to a new user: this is within the remit of each user. Each user is encouraged to view a new attempt at participation here with a human frame of reference vs the disembodied hostility that you suggest is intended and desired.  Not the platitude "be nice" but action that embodies be nice.   In opening review queue to help out in community modding, how do I prevent perpetuationg needless hostility to new users.  New users are my concern: once any of us feels welcome enough to join the scrum, lay on MacDuff!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie My suggestions undermine *nothing* and are an attempt to encourage "be nice" in deed rather that in lip service.  Your advocacy in this interchange of encouraging intentional hostility is explicit support of the  antithesis of "be nice" in deed; be nice at this point comes off as an empty corporate platitude.  Not the first time I've ever seen that, either in this venue or IRL.  Are you playing devil's advocate here (understandable, given your mod role) or is this a sincerely held position?

Comment: You’re saying I’m endorsing intentional hostility, but I’m not. I’m endorsing the barriers that are what makes this site function. They are “structurally hostile” and often received as hostile, but they’re not optional or negotiable. You’re advocating a greater human touch—which is fine in itself. But you’re advicating means that undermine the site mission: (1) treating questions differently based on who asks, (3) treating the askers are more important than their questions. We can be actually nice without drifting the site from the impersonal Q&A it’s designed as, into a personal help site.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Nothing I have suggested in any way undermines the core goal of SE to have a favorable signal to noise ratio to differentiate it from the rest of the internet.  I am about out of interest in further discussion today, so I'll sleep on this; and maybe our discussion has run its course and there's nothing more to say.  I'll see what the sunrise offers in way of inspiration.

Comment: When this answer says things like “How do I know that it's easy to fall into the trap of contributing to barriers to the new user experience?” it’s appearing to conflate all barriers as undesirable—a position we can’t as a community endorse.

Comment: Try not to put words into  my mouth.  Really.  Let's give this an overnight to see if there's anything further to offer, or if I feel inspired to do an edit.

Comment: I have slept on this, and we are indeed done.  These two comments, [1](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/how-is-the-community-doing-2018#comment25784_8069) and [2](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/how-is-the-community-doing-2018#comment25789_8069) in particular are so far wide of the mark, and so wrong in detail, as to leave me even more puzzled, and to conclude that further discourse at this time is fruitless.  Thank you for your time, and the effort, put into the discourse we were able to have.

Answer (score 12):

## There's not much to do here if you don't like Dungeons & Dragons

Try it: put the main D&D tags (dungeons-and-dragons, dnd-5e, dnd-4e, dnd-3.5e, and pathfinder) on your ignore list and look at the main page.

[image: RPG SE front page with most of the content greyed out]

That's more or less how it looks every day.  For everyone trying to do this yourself: on the left, under the "frequent questions" view, there's a "favorite tags" -- you can click "edit" and a list of ignored tags pops up. It's really easy to un-ignore so don't be afraid to play around with this.

I don't have the exact numbers, but my immediate impression is that about 85-90% of the content is D&D content — often quite specific "really only relevant to D&D" content.

That's not a bad thing in some kind of fundamental categorical way, because there's nothing wrong with having a question specifically about Dungeons & Dragons. There's nothing wrong with D&D being by far the most popular category, either: it's a big and popular game.

However, given the sheer volume of D&D over everything else, I think it does mean that the site is rather overspecialized compared to its stated mission. (For context: B&CG did some soul-searching about "are we just a Magic cards website?" after MTG was found to take up about 30-50% of the site.)

I don't know if there's a *solution* here, because, on the face of it, we actually do have an expert base that can answer questions about a significant range of systems (PBTA-style, Fate-based, WoD, many other popular "second-tier" and "indie" games, in a pinch), and I don't think any policies overly favor D&D, but it's worth observing that right now the usage patterns very much make this a D&D-centric site.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed this as well. It seems to have got worse recently and doesn't show any sign of changing given how successful and popular 5e is. Not sure there's anything we can actually do about it though

Comment: Alex, I am not sure how well socialized the use of tags to mask content not desired is, but I think that adding an advocacy or pointer on how to use the tags as you do -- spell it out -- would help any number of folks who feel as you do in terms of D&D saturation. Could you drop in an example of what your mask looks like?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Good point! I added a picture. For everyone trying to do this yourself: on the left, under the "frequent questions" view, there's a "favorite tags" -- you can click "edit" and a list of ignored tags pops up. It's really easy to un-ignore so don't be afraid to play around with this.

Comment: You can also add `*dnd*` to your ignore list, which matches o/adnd or dnd-anything. (`*` can match nothing.)

Comment: I agree this is a thing, and that I’m not sure what, if anything, can or should be done. I’ve often found myself in a period of time playing a non-D&D game and wishing there were more related questions here, but rarely do I have questions about those games to contribute, making it hard to be the change I want to see.

Comment: @AlexP A picture is worth a thousand words.  :)  Thanks. :)  I edited into your answer part of your comment reply to me.  Does it look like it fits there?   If not, another edit to get it to the sweet spot ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Thanks! Your guidance really helped improve this post.

Comment: rpg.se.com is a D&D-centric site, because D&D is the main tabletop rpg. The site reflects the reality of how the hobby is in real life. At least, here, it is easy to filter :)

Comment: Very active users could be cognizant that non D&D questions are rare and could help provide an inviting environment for these questions by ignoring them. Since the most active users are D&D experts, they should avert participation.

Answer (score 10):

### We have an active and healthy chat

The [RPG General Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) is active and remarkably nice. Discussion topics include (but are not limited to) tabletop RPGs, culture, curation of the main site content and birdwatching. Occasional arguments over matters of RPG paradigm flare up, but people are generally very good at managing their passionate opinions. No feuds, no vendettas. The occasional discussion that threatens to "clog the chat" gets neatly extracted to a dedicated side room.

### It could be more open, though

The chat is an excellent place to get more personalized advice in matters not covered by the main site (eg. idea generating questions) as well as to reach out to more experienced site users for informal guidance, but despite the site getting more posts recently, the chat remains rather small - at times it feels more like a secret clubhouse than an open discussion space. The discussion is largely by the same, small set of regulars, with new users finding their way in very infrequently. The chat link being hidden in the footer of the site is not exactly a good way to promote its existence.

I'm in favor of promoting chat to more users, eg. by reinvigorating the [chat event idea](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7099/lets-brainstorm-some-chat-events). However, at the same time, it needs to be stressed that the chat's purpose is not to replace any other site functionality (main or meta) and the present discipline of raising policy questions in Meta instead of "informal" discussion in chat needs to be maintained.

Comment: Chat events didn't really work last time, & I've never actually seen a chat event that increases attendance in the room outside the event itself--and rarely then.

Comment: I agree that chat's great! I think [the role of chat](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3291/4398) is being met quite nicely. Extremely high chat activity has, in the past, [caused problems with mainsite coherence](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6925/4398), making chat mandatory for understanding what's going on in the site proper--leading to resentment and a sense of exclusion by people who don't *want* chat to be part of their Stack experience.

Comment: I think you might get some traction out of digging into what makes chat feel like a "secret clubhouse." If we can better understand those symptoms, perhaps that'll help us diagnose the problem (if any) and prescribe a targeted cure.

Comment: There's also a chat link in the site switcher (but that's also pretty hidden), and some users who are now chat regulars have said they were aware there was a chat from the “moved to chat” comments but just never stopped by for a while.

Comment: Perhaps a functionality of moving a chat sequence to a meta question (or just a general policy for regulars to be aware of for giving a link) would help new users who are asking policy questions in chat become aware of that space (if they aren't already). It could also serve as a reminder to experienced users who forget (me) to use this side of the site for its purpose.

Comment: Let's not forget another common source of links to chat - user comments. I believe many long-term users have a rough template of a welcome message for new users, which may or may not include a chat link. Perhaps we should encourage such links more explicitly. Additionally, these messages seem to be more frequent on problem questions than just newer users. Should we also broaden our scope on such messages?

Comment: @JoelHarmon Several years ago I toyed with pointing new users to the chat alongside the help and tour, but since chat has a 20+ rep floor it mostly just came off as *more* secret-club-like to taunt folks with a thing they can't do (unless I've got a specific reason to invite them personally, I've got a template for that).

Comment: @JoelHarmon I'd love to see a more boilerplate new user language that could copypasta from chat. I generally avoid doing a welcome because i'm not sure what to say or where to link.

Comment: @NautArch ["We could use some more pro-forma comments;"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3519/4398) ["Pre-made comments: A resource-gathering & workshopping thread."](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6168/4398)

Comment: @BESW Well, that makes things easier! Not saying I'll do it, but good to know :)

Comment: Someone could do up a [community ad](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7721/community-promotion-ads-2018) that promotes the main chat room, so it would cycle through the side bar on mainsite.

Comment: I used to use chat a fair bit but haven't for a while, when I tried to rejoin recently it was a real hunt around the UI to try and find the link for it, it's really not obvious - to me anyway!

Answer (score -1):

### This site needs to be humanised

Please don't take this as an attack but I find it amusing that I see this post just after reading the blog (Linked on this very page) about being nicer and more inclusive.

This post is the very definition of the elitist 'don't do this, don't do that' thing that was referenced in that blog.

The 'kindest' sentence:

> We'll post some of the things we've done/observations we have/things
>   we think still need improvement. Please do the same.

You actually used the word please, but managed to make it sound like you are a teacher scolding a naughty pupil.

The site is FULL of that kind of attitude. There seems to be no place for sounding like an actual human and I think that is a shame.

Comment: I don't take it as an attack, and thank you for bringing your concern forward. I will admit, though, that I'm struggling to find a takeaway--I wrote something in just the way I write, so advising me to sound like an actual human (which I think I am) doesn't help *me*, personally. I'd love to hear if you have observations on how word choice conveys that impression (of scolding) or suggestions on phrases to embrace/avoid. Or, going in the other direction, maybe you could pull in some other examples that the site's full of so we can see the pattern for ourselves?

Comment: @nitsua60 I wasn't really writing it as advise personally. It was just a general comment (Your post just happened to be the closest example of something I wanted to say generally) on what I think the community has as a weak point in general. In your case from above the simplest thing is to start with the please, rather than end with it; "Please can you do xyz" not "xyz needs doing. please get it done". One is a request, one is a nicely phrased order. I know you might feel examples are beneficial but I am not sure I want to be picking holes in specific examples, it is just a general thing.

Comment: Given this community is pretty much entirely humans [citation needed] I'm not sure what to take away from this. Your complaint seems to just come down to an opinion about how nitsua60 should have phrased their request, which I'm willing to put down to writing preference. You seem to be indicating there's a much broader "general thing", but I have no idea what that is. We're human, we write like humans, what's the issue here? Please elucidate on what the general thing is.

Comment: @doppelgreener Uh oh, my search results aren't being helpful in grabbing a citation ... *pretty much entirely humans [citation needed]* ... did we get assimilated?  8^o

Comment: @KorvinStarmast [Well there might be some dogs.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KTYKR.jpg) I can't say for sure.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what "attitude" you see in a post asking the community how things are going. Perhaps you should just try reading things more charitably in general because IMO the only way to take this question negatively is to already have a pretty big set of preconceptions.

Comment: @doppelgreener et. al, while I don't think we have a significant tone/politeness problem on the site _in general_, I think that the sarcasm in this comment thread is the kind of antagonistic attitude that SeriousBri's talking about.

Comment: @Icyfire For what it's worth I'm not trying to be antagonistic or sarcastic. I'm trying to understand what someone's complaint is. Was it the citation needed thing? (I mean, I made a sweeping generalisation, maybe it was a poorly timed joke.)

Comment: @doppelgreener I don't think you and and others were being intentionally antagonistic. It's fine if you "read it charitably", as mxyzplk explains, but my first impression after reading these comments was that a bunch of high-rep users were mocking the question by deliberately misinterpreting the word "humanised".

Comment: @Icyfire For me it's not that line, it's the last paragraph of the post I'm responding to: the complaint nobody here can write like an actual human. I don't know how to wrap my head around that when we're a site full of humans writing like humans do, in so many different ways we sometimes have to remind people to respect each others' writing styles when editing. Now, suggesting the site needs to be humanised, that could mean a lot of things in changing how we behave, so hopefully *also* gets helped by explaining what the general pattern is, but human-ness of writing doesn't seem to be missing.

Comment: Yeah, again, try reading what people write charitably.  No one's mocking anyone here.

Comment: Is the focus of this response the way people give procedural guidance (comments, close vote descriptions, FAQ, meta posts, &c.), or the would you say you see a similar problem in the main-site questions and answers themselves?

Answer (score -4):

I think the rules on opinion based answers are a mismatch for a forum which is about role playing games.  Especially some which are deliberately designed to encourage interpretation - which is of course opinion based.

I post mostly on stack overflow, I develop.
The rules on there make sense under most circumstances.
Boolean logic is Boolean logic and your code will work or not work due to fixed rules which are not re-interpreted by any reader.
Even then, development is often more art than science.
I notice some questions there which are closed as opinion based where it's not terribly helpful and I can see the OP really could have done with some help.
Overall the rules generally make sense on Stack Overflow.
Over there if you don't have a "full" answer but have some suggestion to offer then you are actively discouraged from posting an answer.

Stack overflow's rules seem to have been adopted as is for dnd 5.
Since rpg is largely opinion based this seems an inherent mismatch.
Maybe someone should be considering whether somewhat different rules ought to apply.
What seems particularly strange is where different rules already apply.
Any comment that could be interpreted as helpful ( some sort of an answer ) gets deleted.  This seems particularly strange and I don't see how that helps anyone or makes the site better.

Comment: On that last paragraph, see [Why are site comments getting deleted?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/why-are-site-comments-being-deleted) — and all we're doing is actually enforcing Stack Exchange rules that Stack Overflow can't enforce because the volume of work there is too high so they focus on higher priority issues. As for opinion oriented stuff, is there anything specific you think we're missing support for that we should support? We've done our best to adapt the rules to our circumstances and it tends to work fairly well for us, but we're open to improvements.

Comment: See also [we are not a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2709/23970) and [my question is better-suited to a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970) for some of the historical discussion around what Stacks are good at vs. not. To be clear: it may be wise to periodically revisit those notions, so thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: "Any comment that could be interpreted as helpful ( some sort of an answer ) gets deleted." This usually occurs after the information in the comment has been incorporated into the question or answer through revisions. The purpose of comments is for question/answer improvement, so once the improvement is handled (or declined) then the comment doesn't serve any purpose anymore. Essentially, comments are like proof-reader's marks. They help improve the draft of the document, but eventually you redact them. Their purpose has been served.

Comment: ...And if "some sort of answer" is posted in a comment then that's not helpful to the site in general because all the normal mechanisms available for searching, voting, and displaying answers is useless when an answer is buried somewhere in a comment. When answers-in-comments get deleted, there is almost always a warning to re-post as an answer, to make sure it gets categorized in a way that can be _more_ helpful.

Comment: @Bloodcinder True. I, for one, delete comment-answers the moment I see them regardless of whether it looks like the author incorporated, rejected, or even saw them. And to be clear, I'm even talking about things that seem to newish users as helpful and innocuous, like "you should check out xyz.org/essay-on-your-thing, it's really useful." (Nvm earlier version--we're simul-commenting. Edited for standalone-ness.)

Comment: Just to be clear here, I am most definitely not criticising people who are doing their best to implement rules. I'm not complaining about people stifling my creativity or something.  The rules are made and moderators implement those rules. I think the rules as they stand  have a negative effect on the site usefulness.  I think they are also likely to discourage new posters... Or those that think form should suit purpose. Better.

Comment: So oddly, we have thought about it.  In fact, Stack Exchange has, and there's guidance that's normative for all the other sites.  See the SE blog post "Good Subjective, Bad Subjective": https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/   RPGs are not completely opinion-based - answers can derive from experience, or they can just be people wagging their jaws.  There are plenty of forums for the latter - SE is not a forum, as nitsua60 points out.

Comment: Hey Andy, just a note on your “adopted as-is for D&D 5e” and “**a** roleplaying game” (my emphasis, quoting the original edit of your post): beware that RPG.se regularly covers dozens or hundreds of RPGs other than D&D 5e, and that there are *thousands* of RPGs in existence that we potentially cover. Being careful to not mistake RPG.se as for only D&D 5th edition can help avoid some common *faux pas*, like writing answers for the wrong game or neglecting to mention the game a question is about.

Comment: @Andy D&D 5e came out in 2014. (play test began IIRC 2012) ... RPG.SE began in 2010 ish ... ;)

Comment: @nitsua60 A link to an answer is not an answer.  A non-answer consisting of a link posted as an answer is closed as "not an answer".  Deleting a link to resources because it is a partial answer doesn't make sense in that context; it is "not an answer", it is a sign pointing where an answer may be.  Do you have a link to a policy about deleting comments that links, as opposed to answers?

Comment: @yakk that's a fine attempt at logic twist, but link only answers aren't "not an answer" in some cosmic logical sense, they are poor and disallowed answers. Posting it in a comment isn't ok because poor, partial, etc. answers in comments are also not OK. https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments

Answer (score -8):

## Concrete vs Abstract Reasoning

One of the most frustrating hurdles I come across in the various SE sub-sites is moderators who are quick to put a question on hold, because **the moderator** (or even a group of moderators), cannot grasp the context of the question.  This might be due to the questioner being a poor communicator.  It might also be due to the fact that I have a very high intuitive ability.

Regardless, moderators put a question on hold, and I'm looking at it thinking "this is easy to answer, you just have to suss out the questioner's context a bit".  As a new user who's had this happen to him, I can tell you it's quite embarrassing to have your comment put on hold, because it's "off topic" when you're quite sure it's on topic, and you just don't know how better to express what you're trying to get across.  In fact, from your perspective, the meaning couldn't be more clear, and you don't understand why you're having to babystep adults through your already clearly communicated issue.

Regardless of what you might think of the MBTI test, I liken it to the difference between Sensors and Intuitors, which is doubly apt in my mind, since a lot of SE is comprised of software developers who tend to be Sensors.  Let me define these two words:

- Sensor: This is a person who processes input from the world around them via concrete reasoning.  They must step through A, B, C, and D to get to E or they will get lost.  They will not assume any intermediate steps, unless they can personally experience those steps.
- Intuitor: This is a person who processes input from the world around them via abstract reasoning.  If they see A, C, D and E, they will assume B and F and keep on trucking.  This might get them into trouble from time-to-time, but if they feel like they've got 80% of the data, they know they're probably okay to assume the other 20%.

This is a very base description, as no person is all one or the other.  It's a sliding scale, and each person falls on that scale somewhere.  As a high Intuitor, I can tell you I often see patterns and can pick out other peoples' meaning even when they've done a very poor job of communicating their thoughts.

In an environment like this one, it is the Sensors who are going to tend to rise through the ranks fastest, as they are most likely to follow the rules to the letter, and to punish those who fail to follow the rules.

By the same token, it is the Intuitors who are most likely to allow things to slide, to get taken down a path as it were that the site expressly forbids, because they "kinda get where the other person is coming from" and so don't need them to follow the rules to still achieve the desired result.

I'm not saying either one is better or worse.  Both are excellent for some things and terrible for others, but it certainly helps explain the greatest areas of tensions between the two types of users, especially new users.

More to the point, I don't think this is the type of thing you can teach someone.  It's kind of hard-wired into people.  But I believe it's the biggest reason certain types of users are driven away, and why the moderators seem to exist within their own echo chamber.  They will naturally agree with each other, especially because they all will tend to view sticking to the rules of the site the same way.  To people like me, it's going to feel very draconian, and that's coming from someone who sees the other perspective.

To wit, me and a lead developer at my first job would have legendary arguments.  We couldn't talk about anything for more than 5 minutes without shouting at each other.  We were clearly at opposite ends of the spectrum.  He'd regularly shout the words, "You can't know that!" or "You can't make that assumption!"  Whereas, I'd be the one shouting, "Christ, you can see X, Y, and A1.  Z HAS TO FALL IN BETWEEN!"

It's worse when people operate under the common misconception that "Other people think like me."  I used to despise people who *refused to talk about the obvious elephant in the room*.  It took me years to realize that I really was the only person who could see it, and that it was my responsibility to walk the rest of the group through the process to get to the point I'd been standing on for weeks.  Moreover, that same realization is what allowed me greatly value what other people brought to the table, even when it wasn't my brilliant ability to intuit seemingly unconnected events.  The diligence embodied in the aforementioned software developer is what made him really great at his job.  He is, bar none, the best developer I have ever known.

How does this translate here?  I don't know.  I'm just trying to draw a road map of the problem.

**Optimizing for Sand, and Smashing the Pearls**

SevenSidedDie turned my on to [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), which describes why StackExchange shifted their focus to questions.  Having read that post, I have a much better understanding of how the leadership of SE has actually helped to create the problem I've described above.

> If we don’t do our part to cull the bad questions, then we risk
> alienating the true experts who provide what really matters: the
> answers!

This quote took me by surprise.  I had to read it a few times, because the context seemed very strange in terms of an effort to better serve the *community*.  That is, until you realize that the community is the answerers, and not the questioners.  If StackExchange were a for-profit enterprise charging for answers, it'd go out of business very quickly.  No one will pay to be insulted, regardless of how much of an expert the answerer is.

I am a recognized industry expert in a highly technical field.  I've written dozens of whitepapers, given talks to groups of 80+ people.  I worked at my first company for 15 years and established myself with companies around the world.  5 years after leaving, I still have customers hunting down my cell number to talk to me.

I used to troubleshoot extremely complex industrial equipment over the phone.  It was great when I could teach my customers to contact me with the right information (Asking the right question in the right way), but much of the time I had to guide them through the process to get to the answer.  Had I taken the attitude that I couldn't or wouldn't help you without properly formatting your questions, I would not have the reputation I have today.

This site doesn't exist to stroke the egos of some experts.  It exists to help people around the world find answers to their questions.  Based on some of the comments below, some people have either lost sight of that, or they couldn't care less.  The questioners are your customers, guys.  I don't care that they aren't paying for the service.

> Perhaps you’ve noticed a theme here. Incoming questions are a
> universal constant, all around us in countless billions. But answers —
> truly brilliant, amazing, correct answers — are as rare as pearls.
> Thus, questions are merely the sand that produces the pearl. If we
> have learned anything in the last three years, it is that you optimize
> for pearls, not sand.

This quote is a stunning mindset.  Questions are merely the sand that produces the pearl?  Holy cow, what an arrogant mindset.  If your experts are so full of pearls, why don't they just sit down and write wikis on their specific areas of knowledge?  Then, all the low-sloping foreheads can muddle through searches of wikis-of-wisdom to find the answers they seek.

There's a weird set of mutually exclusive mindsets at work at StackExchange.  An Executive Vice President writes a post that he wants SE to come off as friendlier, easier to use, more inclusive.  Yet, here's a co-founder explaining why that will never happen.  It demonstrates that SE really doesn't have alignment from top-to-bottom in the organization.

Comment: It can indeed be frustrating, but let me suggest two points. 1) There's nothing shameful about having a question put on hold. It's of course alarming the first few times it happens, but it's not like getting banned or censured or anything like that. There's no reason to be embarrassed by it. Ideally, when the question is getting put on hold and the asker is a new user, somebody will point that out to avoid having a sour experience.

Comment: 2) Although the asker might think it's clear and some members might think it's clear, the goal is for everything on SE to be clear to everybody, not just to specific people. I too have had occasions where I couldn't figure out why other people didn't understand something "obvious," but since not everybody is me (or you) and not everybody has the same ability to fill in the gaps and infer subtext, it's helpful to the community as a whole to be able to clarify above and beyond to make sure that the information makes sense to the widest audience.

Comment: I think the community could take steps to make the on-hold process seem less embarrassing and punishment-like, but I don't think it should be at the expense of maximizing clarity for the general audience.

Comment: @Bloodcinder If you have suggestions for how the on-hold process could be improved, a separate meta question would be the ideal place to explore them. It's worth noting, however, that that process is the same across all Stack Exchange sites so asking on the primary meta site would be a necessary step in the process.

Comment: Hey, I guess I'm a sensor, because I'm not sure I'm correctly intuiting what you're getting at. Could you be more specific about how this applies to this site and this community, in particular?

Comment: We put on hold so that it can be 'sussed out a bit.'

Comment: @ObliviousSage I'm not actually talking about the policy or mechanical process, just a bit more consistency with the friendliness of application. It's a pretty common complaint that new users feel intimidated by the on-hold process. I often see good use of "welcome but this question needs to be put on hold for the following reasons" messages, but sometimes there's no such message and the first thing a new user perceives is a sequence of brusque admonishments, like they're being graded.

Comment: Answerability isn't a factor in whether a question is put on hold. Questions get put on hold because they don't fit the site's definition of acceptable questions: you could ask "What is 2+2?" and it would still be closed as off-topic, even though it's easy to answer.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl Yeah, I realized that and deleted that comment (apparently right before you posted yours). I also disagree with this answer--in my experience as an intuitor, I've found that the more you leave people to do their own "abstract reasoning," the more wildly divergent their interpretations become. As a site dedicated to solving real problems, I think we should strive to be as concrete as possible, if only for the sake of good communication.

Comment: I have an interesting perspective here. Before I became a mod, I semi-regularly “rescued” questions that were semi-incoherent. I am on the Intuitor side of the spectrum, and would see a post that others were voting “unclear” and be able to tell what they were meaning to ask. I'd do a complete rewrite, ask if that said what they meant, and it would often get “yes!” and reopened. I'd semi-regularly get into arguments with closing mods that a question was fine. **Now** I'm a mod… and I understand more now that mods have limited time. We apply the rules, move on, and hope people fix their posts.

Comment: One thing that hasn't changed though: I understood then and now that the *text* needed to clearly say to everyone what they were meaning the text to say. My editing then (when I had that flexible time) was toward that goal. My holding now (as a mod with limited moderation time) is still toward that goal. I wish we had someone who liked rescuing questions to take the place of old-me, but on the other hand, encouraging askers to revise their own posts is not a bad thing either.

Comment: I just want to add that it's not always a moderator that closes or holds a question. It recieves votes from memebers with enough rep. It's rare that I see any of the diamonds close a question by themselves. I'm not a moderator and I have enough rep to add a close-vote to a question.

Comment: Agree with SSD - part of the benefit of closing is helping teach those posters how to effectively use their words.  ‘Oh but 10% of the site can figure out what they are saying” is not an acceptable endgame.  They can improve so most of the site does.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie the biggest factor in rescuing questions is usually figuring out the system, which is verboten. With that consensus in place, bad questions aren't even worth sifting through.

Comment: @fectin  *the biggest factor in rescuing questions is usually figuring out the system, which is verboten* I don't understand what you mean by that.  I've tried to rescue some questions but I am not sure I come to that the way SSD has approached it.  Getting the system clear is a common request for clarification, not "verboten."  (can you help me understand what you meant?)

Comment: I engaged in a bunch of question-rescue edits as well during 2014-2016. Usually the system was clearly stated, but the question was a mess, expressed in a super muddled fashion or with poor English or it was one giant mega-paragraph or it was 10 paragraphs when it could just be 2. There'd be comments asking what they meant and close votes. If we could discern their angle we'd edit then ask if the new revision matched what they meant; if we weren't certain we'd check what we thought their angle was with them first in comments *then* revise. We'd still VTC, and reopen once the dust settled.

Comment: +1 for this. I regularly wonder why things are being put on hold when the meaning is frankly 100% clear to me. Given the legalese in some of the answers made by the people who put posts on hold I do wonder about comprehension. On a side note this is brilliant information for me personally - I am often the one wondering why people don't understand things, and it is probably because they are sensors!

Comment: @SeriousBri Thanks.  The comments are interesting.  Some of the commenters make excellent points, to which neither they nor I have a ready answer.  Some have clearly taken this very personally, and others have a response akin to "figure it out, it works great the way it is".  Seems like the built-in inertia of SE wins again.

Comment: As a corollary, just peruse the answers above.  The more the answer reflects positively on the status quo, the more upvotes it receives.  SE is a self-licking ice cream cone.

Comment: @Bloodcinder Shame is in the eye of the beholder, and often it is unclear as to why a question is put on hold.  I suppose you and I have a lot of very different experiences, because most "On Hold" questions that I see lack clarification.  You and I do not disagree on keeping maximum clarity.  Our perspectives on achieving it might be at odds, but at no time have I suggested that clarity should suffer.

Comment: @Icyfire I don't know how to convey the context of my meaning more clearly than I have, and yet you seem to have walked away with a 180 degree understanding of my communication.  In my mind, this underscores a large part of the problem.  Cheers.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You and bloodcinder both seem to take the same approach, which is a great one, but tough to implement consistently unless you specifically recruit people for this purpose and they spend a lot of time doing it.  I'm more inclined to seek a mechanical solution for it, even if the mechanic is more about gently conveying the message to the OP that they need to re-ask their question.  I'm not saying that's my suggestion, but it's an example of what I think we're all talking about.

Comment: @Jason_c_o Is there a good explanation somewhere of how that works?  I've seen very few closed questions due to votes, and many more with specific user names attached, so our experiences are at opposite ends of the spectrum, and I don't understand the mechanism.

Comment: @mxyzplk I don't think I suggested that just because a tiny percentage of people can quickly reason out peoples' meaning that all moderation of questions should be abandoned, but thanks for contributing.

Comment: @fectin I also would like clarification on your comment.  Until your final sentence, I thought I was following you.

Comment: @user9570789 The names attached are the members with enough reputation that voted to close. Once a post receives enough close votes it displays the reason with the most votes and the handles of those that voted. They don't necessarily need to be mods.

Comment: @Jason_c_o Thank you!  That was the part that I didn't understand.  Intuitively, and based on how it works in most other places, that's the opposite of what I thought.  This kind of thing should be part of the "tour".

Comment: The [tour] can only cover so much (testing shows that even as short as it is, few bother to read the whole thing). For details like how holds and closes work, there's the [Help].

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but I downvoted this because I've reread it several times and still have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: @korvinstarmast my reply seems to have been deleted as "too random". Not sure what else to do there.

Comment: @fectin Was that answer you posted meant to be a comment on this answer? You could still go ahead and post it here as a comment on this answer. You'd posted it in its own answer, which is why it got removed -- answers aren't for pinging someone with a short message or whatnot, and I was pretty confused with seeing that coming from a well-established user and was sure there'd been a mistake entering in the wrong field.

Comment: @Miniman I agree, especially after the follow-up comments. I've tried to parse the user's comment @'d at me and I can't tell what the point is. Considering the topic, this may be ironic.

Comment: Unclear questions get closed, period. That is the long-tested, tried-and-true approach that the Stack Exchange model is built on. It’s a shame how that *appears* to new users, and I’m all for ways of improving the appearance (the use of “on hold” for one example), but the actual closing *needs to happen*. Questions need to be clear before they can be answered, and they should be closed in the meantime; even if we can’t help from making that “look bad” or “feel bad,” we still need to do it.

Comment: As for other users editing in the clarity that is “obvious” to them, I am certainly convinced that I don’t want *you* doing it—you have not demonstrated the skills you claim to have in this area. And @SevenSidedDie may remember a whole lot of “yes!” in response to his edits, but I remember a whole lot of his edits unilaterally changing the meaning and substance of a question without so much as a comment to the user. It was often rude and we often argued about it. I think this is a vastly better place than it was *precisely because* he is no longer doing that.

Comment: @KRyan The ones I’m thinking of weren’t related to tags or perceived XY problems, if those are what you’re thinking of. (I’d go find a revision example, but it seems my revision action history alone runs to 600+ pages…)

Comment: @user9570789 of the 9 answers posted, only one of them is "reflecting positively on the status quo" the rest are pointing out ways in which the site needs to be improved. So, I'm not sure where that critique is coming from.

Comment: @Miniman & Bloodcinder It’s saying that a certain type of question gets closed as “unclear” too much, due to no fault in the questions, only due to how most voters are a certain kind of communicator/thinking style, and it makes them feel unwelcome as a member of the minority style. It’s feedback to the “how’re things?” question rather than feedback + proposed fix. (Which is okay. A recognised problem should have a whole later meta of its own, so it’s not the job of one person to both see & fix it.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I’m not denying that you “got it right” often—I’m denying that you *really knew* ahead of time which ones you were getting right, and that the ones you got right weren’t worth the ones you got wrong. Worse, many you changed and then we never got any feedback from the original querent as to whether it was appropriate. In short, at least in your case, and in 9570789’s case, I really don’t think you *do* have any great “intuitive” insight that others lack. What I think you have is a willingness to assume your own perspective is the right one. And I don’t think that’s appropriate.

Comment: @KRyan I think you aren’t active in the tags where these occurred. We’ve never argued about the type of “rescue” I’m talking about.

Comment: Your latest edit seems to turn this post into more of a rant, and Im afraid I've lost sight of what you're trying to say, specifically. You call yourself a "genius intuitor" but could not intuit how close-votes work. I don't mean to be abrasive, but I find what you're doing harmful and am seeing old hostilities between longer-standing members emerge in the comments to this answer that I haven't seen in about 2 years.

Comment: Ah, I see where the misunderstanding is. You’ve assumed this is a *help site*, when it’s a *Q&A site*. The distinction may not be obvious, so let’s look at the purpose of each. A help site has the purpose you stated (“to help people around the world find answers to their questions.”). This Q&A site doesn’t have that purpose; its purpose is to create a curated database of easily-searched knowledge. Questions exist only to prompt knowledge-submissions and be searchable. Each Q&A is intended to serve later readers; helping the asker is only incidental. Weird, eh? But that’s the goal.

Comment: Note: Stack Exchange *is* for profit. Profit comes from ads, from Careers on some sites, and in future from things like Teams. "This site doesn't exist to stroke the egos of some experts. It exists to help people around the world find answers to their questions." Absolutely true, but the subtle twist that makes the genius in the sites is that the *post called a question*, the one that gets the answers attached, doesn't have to be *their* question. Upwards of 90% of people on SE get their question answered *without asking it*, via search.

Comment: @fectin I finally understand [what you were referring to](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43254682#43254682).  [The oxen are slow, but the earth is patient](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085678/quotes?item=qt0133370). :)